# Domination $\Rightarrow$ $0$ equality

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

Let $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$. In class, my teacher said that the dominated convergence theorem (DOM) may be used to prove that
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} \! \log |x| \phi'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x =0.
$$
**My question is :** How to apply DOM in this particular case ?

**My thoughts :** I thought it would be sufficient to show that, given any sequence $(\epsilon_n)_{n \geq 1} \subset \mathbb{R_{> 0}}$ such that $\epsilon_n \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \! \log |x| \phi'(x) 1_{[-\epsilon_n, \epsilon_n]} \, \mathrm{d}x = 0.
$$
In order to prove this, I would first note that
$$
\log |x| \phi'(x) 1_{[-\epsilon_n, \epsilon_n]} \to 0 \text{ a.e.}
$$
when $n \to \infty$ (here I write a.e. because the function is infinite at $x = 0$), and then note that
$$
\left| \log |x| \phi'(x) 1_{[-\epsilon_n, \epsilon_n]} \right| \leq |\log|x| \phi'(x)|
$$
where $|\log|x| \phi'(x)| \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R})$ (I take for granted that $\log |x| \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}))$. Hence DOM can be applied and the conclusion follows.

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's correct. But if we know that $|log |x||$ is locally integrable we can make the proof shorter, as 
$$\left|\int_{-\varepsilon}^{+\varepsilon}\log |x|\phi'(x)\mathrm dx\right|\leqslant 
2\sup_{t\in\mathbb R}|\phi'(t)|\int_0^{\varepsilon}|\log x|\mathrm dx.$$